# How to use tweepy search query containing only brackets or signs

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to use tweepy to search for tweets containing only brackets or signs.

The command is:

```
tweets = auth.search(q="[@", count=100)
```

But I get the following error:

> tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Missing or invalid url
>   parameter.', u'code': 195}]

Any ideas on how to search it correctly? I tried `\\\\[\\\@` and `\\[\@` also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want tweets containing only brackets OR signs, I believe you have to put an additional argument. I use a different library to do it (https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python) where I can just type q="this or that". But you also may run into issues because the twitter search will try to ignore characters like hashtag, punctuation, @, etc. Good luck, hope this helps.